# Persisting data from Apache Storm, any Framework?

Tags: database, persistence, apache-kafka, apache-storm, trident

We are using Kafka-storm in our project. In storm we will use multiple bolts for transformations. But before that, as part of POC, we want to persist data into DB. Which framework we should use? For BigData scenario which can be used? Is Trident applicable here? For persistence I am looking for something like Hibernate/JPA. What can be used? and if possible provide a sample code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use almost any framework you want, although your specific choice may impact your topology slightly.  Choose your favorite framework and give it a try.

Comment: I was thinking of EclipseLink. But I don't know whether this will be ideal for real-time analytics scenario and there is the question. Mostly for storing such data is it ok? And what for is this Trident?